# Can you add ActionScript or other code to an flv

Tags: actionscript, flv

I'm curious if it's possible for an flv file to contain code like ActionScript or if it can only contain the audio/video data for the video.

I'm specifically asking related to the security of allowing an FLV file to be uploaded a site.

Edit: assume that the contents have been validated to be a real "flv" - the question is whether the format natively supports code inside of the flv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the question is whether the format natively supports code inside of
>   the flv.

To that question, the answer is no. For further security discussions, see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

FLV files are for video/audio: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video. but I can rename any executable file of course and add the .FLV extension to it. so I believe you will need to read the uploaded files and check whether they are FLV indeed.

Answer (score 0):

FLV is only a video format. Like akonsu said, you should check if the file is really a FLV file, not just checking it's extension.

You should check if the file's [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) is "**video/x-flv**".

More info about FLV: http://osflash.org/flv